# CNN model with both image data and pre-extracted features

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement a `CNN model` to classify some images to their corresponding classes. Images are of size `64x64x3`. My dataset consists of 25,000 images and also a `CSV` file consisting of `14 pre-extracted features` like color, length etc.

I want to build a `CNN` model that make use of both the image data and the features for training and prediction. How can I implement such a model in `Python` with `Keras`.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to start out assuming that you can import the data without any issues, and you have already separated the x-data into Image and Features, and you have the y data as the labels of each image.

You can use the keras functional api to have a neural network take multiple inputs.

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Dense, Input, Embedding, multiply, Reshape, concatenate

img = Input(shape=(64, 64, 3))
features = Input(shape=(14,))
embedded = Embedding(input_dim=14, output_dim=60*32)(features)
embedded = Reshape(target_shape=(14, 60,32))(embedded)

encoded = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(img)
encoded = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(encoded)

x = concatenate([embedded, encoded], axis=1)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
main_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='main_output')(x)

model = Model([img, features], [main_output])
```

Comment: Can you tell me how you came up with the number `60*32` for `output_dim`

Comment: Output of encoded after the second Conv2D becomes (None, 60, 60, 32). For concatenate to merge the two outputs together they must same shape except in 1 axis. 60*32 is reshaped into (14, 60, 32), which lets us concat on axis 1. If this solution answers your question, please consider marking it as accepted.